# Upload a file using HTML and Perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am trying to do a simple upload of a .csv file and save it on my server.  I'm not an expert in HTML or Perl, but due to client constraints this is what I must do.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="/path/to/service" target="_self" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File: <input type="file" name="attachment" size="50">
<SUBMIT_RESET Upload File>
</form>
```

The Perl code looks like this:

```
    my $sql = "SELECT NOW()";
    my $date = $DB->get_field($sql);

    my ($path, $ext) = split(/\./, $in{'attachment'});
    my @pathParts = split(/\//, $path);            
    my $filename = $pathParts[@pathParts - 1] . " - " . $date;

    if ($ext eq "csv") {                

        open (OUTFILE, ">", "$datadir/imports/" . $filename . "." . $ext);

        while (read($in{'attachment'}, $buffer, 1024)) {
            $file .= $buffer;
        }
        print OUTPUT $file;
        close (OUTFILE);
    }
```

Can anyone please give me some direction as to what I'm doing wrong.  I get the file located at the correct path, but it's always empty.

Now, the code base I'm dealing with here is horrible and I cannot use strict.

Suggestions?

EDIT1:
To attempt to answer how $in{'attachment'} is populated I've included a snippet of code of how forms are handled.

if ($ENV{'CONTENT_TYPE'} =~ m#^multipart/form-data#) {
            my $cgi = new CGI;
            my @names = $cgi->param;

```
        foreach $name (@names) {
            my @value = $cgi->param($name);
            if (scalar(@value) > 1) {
                foreach $val (@value) {
                    $in{$name} .= $val."\0";
                }
                $in{$name} =~s/\\0$//;
            } else {
                my $value = $cgi->param($name);
                #my $value = join "\0", @value;
                $in{$name} = $value;
            }
            #my $value = $cgi->param($name);
            #my $value = join "\0", @value;
            #$in{$name} = $value;
        }
```

EDIT2:

To summarize the solution provided by ikegami...

I missed that the file handles were different for the read and print statements - `OUTFILE` and `OUTPUT`.  Clearly that is completely a novice mistake and for that I apologize!

Best wishes to all who tried to help me.

Comment: How was `$in{'attachment'}` populated?

Comment: I am assuming that $in{'attachment'} is the filehandle to read the attachment.  Try putting this before any reads.

binmode $in{'attachment'};

Comment: @Robert Hanson, It could also Rico assumes the same.

Comment: You can use strict in block (`{ use strict; ... }`) including in a sub (`sub foo { use strict; ... }`) without affecting anything around it.

Comment: I've tried using the binmode - no go.  The `$in{'attachment'}` is populated by a .cgi file that pushes all POSTED information into a global hash (let's all shriek together).  I'm going to try to put the use strict in a block and see what I get there.

Comment: No go on the `use strict;` in blocks.  This code is very easily the messiest code I've ever worked with.

Comment: How was `$in{'attachment'}` populated? *specifically*! You didn't provide your input, and the problem is your input.

Comment: (Please use a message containing @ikegami to let me know when you address this)

Comment: It would be helpful to have the version of perl and whether the .cgi file that is grabbing the form data is a homegrown script or a known cgi handler. If you're able, add a line like `warn ref $in{attachment};` to see if it's really a filehandle (you should see `IO`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using global variables. If your file handles had been lexical variables (supported since 2000!) and if you had been using `use strict;` (also supported since 2000, if not earlier!), you would have found the problem:

You're not using the right variable in your `print` call.

```
open (OUTFILE, ">", "$datadir/imports/" . $filename . "." . $ext);
print OUTPUT $file;
```

---

When I discovered the problem, I was about to recommend you find out what error you actually got:

```
open(my $OUTFILE, ">", "$datadir/imports/$filename.$ext")
   or die $!;

while (1) {
   my $rv = read($in{'attachment'}, my $buf, 1024);
   die $! if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;

   print $OUTFILE $buf
      or die $!;
}

close($OUTFILE)
   or die $!;
```

(I was going to hypothesise that the error was "`Bad file descriptor`" due to passing something that isn't a file handle to `read`.)

Comment: Totally missed the filehandle assigned.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>File Upload</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form action="upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <p>Photo to Upload: <input type="file" name="photo" /></p> 
        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></p> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Perl Code** under the file name upload.cgi:

```
#!C:\Program Files\perl\bin\perl.exe

use strict; 
use CGI; 
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser ); 
use File::Basename; 
$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000; 
my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-"; 
my $upload_dir = "fileUpload/"; 
my $query = new CGI; my $filename = $query->param("photo"); 
if ( !$filename ) 
{ 
    print $query->header ( ); 
    print "There was a problem uploading your photo (try a smaller file)."; 
    exit; 
} 
my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '..*' ); 
$filename = $name . $extension; 
$filename =~ tr/ /_/; $filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g; 
if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ ) 
{ 
    $filename = $1; 
} else { 
    die "Filename contains invalid characters"; 
} 
my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo"); 
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!"; 
binmode UPLOADFILE; 
while ( <$upload_filehandle> ) 
{ 
    print UPLOADFILE; 
} 
close UPLOADFILE;
print $query->header ( ); 
print <<END_HTML; 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Thanks!</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
img {border: none;} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p>Thanks for uploading your photo!</p> 
</body> 
</html> 
END_HTML
```

I did not write this code, but it did help me alot. I hope it helps you as well. What made this code work for me was getting the path to perl.exe right.